# Bash Terminal (What's up with the Errors?)

Tags: 21.04

Why do these lines appear whenever I open my Terminal?

```
declare -x COLORTERM="truecolor"
declare -x DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS="unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus"
declare -x DESKTOP_SESSION="ubuntu"
declare -x DISPLAY=":0"
declare -x GDMSESSION="ubuntu"
declare -x GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID="this-is-deprecated"
declare -x GNOME_SETUP_DISPLAY=":1"
declare -x GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE="ubuntu"
declare -x GNOME_TERMINAL_SCREEN="/org/gnome/Terminal/screen/26af51d8_cc15_4fc2_af45_c5eb83fd18d4"
declare -x GNOME_TERMINAL_SERVICE=":1.284"
declare -x GTK_MODULES="gail:atk-bridge"
declare -x HOME="/home/frederickpina"
declare -x IM_CONFIG_PHASE="1"
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
declare -x LOGNAME="frederickpina"
declare -x OLDPWD
declare -x PATH="/opt/firefox/firefox:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/snap/bin"
declare -x PWD="/home/frederickpina"
declare -x QT_ACCESSIBILITY="1"
declare -x QT_IM_MODULE="ibus"
declare -x SESSION_MANAGER="local/frederickpina-HP-Spectre-x360-Convertible:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1461,unix/frederickpina-HP-Spectre-x360-Convertible:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1461"
declare -x SHELL="/bin/bash"
declare -x SHLVL="1"
declare -x SSH_AGENT_LAUNCHER="gnome-keyring"
declare -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/1000/keyring/ssh"
declare -x TERM="xterm-256color"
declare -x USER="frederickpina"
declare -x USERNAME="frederickpina"
declare -x VTE_VERSION="6203"
declare -x WAYLAND_DISPLAY="wayland-0"
declare -x XAUTHORITY="/run/user/1000/.mutter-Xwaylandauth.O6V940"
declare -x XDG_CONFIG_DIRS="/etc/xdg/xdg-ubuntu:/etc/xdg"
declare -x XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP="ubuntu:GNOME"
declare -x XDG_DATA_DIRS="/usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop"
declare -x XDG_MENU_PREFIX="gnome-"
declare -x XDG_RUNTIME_DIR="/run/user/1000"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_CLASS="user"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP="ubuntu"
declare -x XDG_SESSION_TYPE="wayland"
declare -x XMODIFIERS="@im=ibus"

frederickpina@frederickpina-HP-Spectre-x360-Convertible:~$
```

Comment: Most likely you have a malformed `export` (or `declare -x`) line in your `~/.bashrc` file. They're not errors btw, just a list of all the variables that have been exported.

Comment: See where it happens with `bash -x ~/.bashrc`.